# htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Session is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nullreferenceexception, httpcontext

I am trying to use an `HtmlHelper` in an `MVC` project that I'm working on but am hung up on this problem. Why is `Session` null when I try to call the helper method in my nav/menu partial on page load? It works anywhere else I use it in the project but when I try and use it in my layout or menu partial I get this null reference exception.

```
public static class HtmlHelpers
{
    public static ApplicationUser UserInformation(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        var httpContext = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext;

        if (httpContext.Session["CurrentUser"] == null)
        {
            // Get user information
            var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
            var applicationUser = userManager.FindById(httpContext.user.Identity.GetUserId());

            httpContext.Session["CurrentUser"] = applicationUser;
        }

        return (ApplicationUser) httpContext.Session["CurrentUser"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` rather than `htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext`.

**Example :**

```
 var httpContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;

     if (httpContext.Session["CurrentUser"] == null)
    {
        // Do somthing.
    }
```

You can get more information about [session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session(v=vs.100).aspx) in here.

**OR**

```
public static ApplicationUser UserInformation(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    if (httpContext.Session["CurrentUser"] == null)
    {

    } 
}
```

You can get more information about  [session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase.session(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I tried that but I'm still getting the same null reference exception. Thanks for the suggestion though.